# Elastic Search: ES-PHP Client how to create GEOPOINT Index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an index that should contain GEOPoint by using the Elastic Search PHP client -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/5.0/index.html

My Code is as follow

```
    $params = [
         'index' => 'sweden_codes',
         'type' => 'sweden_c',
         'body' => [
                    'mappings' => [
                        'location' => [
                            'properties' => [
                                'pin' => [
                                    'properties' => [
                                        'location' => [
                                            'type' => 'geo_point'
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                             ]
                        ],
                        'text' => $code->City,
                        'pin' => [
                            'location' => [
                                'lat' => $code->Latitude,
                                'lon' => $code->Longitude
                            ]
                         ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
      $client = ClientBuilder::create()
               ->setSSLVerification(false)
               ->setHosts(["elasticsearch:9200"])->build();
```

The Problem is when i go into kibana it say " No Compatible Fields: The "sweden_codes" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point"

can anyone please have a look into the issue and let me know whats wrong with my mapping and index creation

Here is the Code for Mappings that works for me

```
   $params = [
            'index' => 'sweden_postal_codes',
            'body' => [
                'mappings' => [
                    'codes' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'location' => [
                                'type' => 'geo_point'
                            ],
                            'city' => [
                                'type' => 'string'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ];

        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setSSLVerification(false)
            ->setHosts(["elasticsearch:9200"])->build();

        // Adding the index into the ES Cluster

         $response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

Here is the code for document indexing that worked for me

```
 $params = [
            'index' => 'sweden_postal_codes',
            'type' => 'codes',
            'id' => 2,
            'body' => [
                'location' => [
                    'lat' => 30.5268956,
                    'lon' => 79.2289643
                ],
                'city' => 'Stockholm'
            ]
        ];

        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setSSLVerification(false)
            ->setHosts(["elasticsearch:9200"])->build();

        // Adding the index into the ES Cluster

        $response = $client->index($params);
```

Comment: and the last line is $client->index($params); just add the index

Comment: Hi Guys I somehow manage to fix it, First we need to separate the mappings and document indexing so the code is here